# Certificate fingerprint (SHA1) should I change it with release Certificate?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am new to Google Play Game Services and recently managed to include it to an app. I generated a Certificate fingerprint with a terminal using this commant on MAC to test it:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

My question is, when I upload my app to my dev account, should I change the certificate from debug to release? If yes, how can I do that?

is it using the same command but instead of "debug.keystore" -> release.keystore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will need to change it. See that your using `androiddebugkey`. When you release the app you will need to sign the app and then use the same key to generate the certificate.

If you using Android Studio, you can easily create a new key store and a new key alias. (Build -> Generate Signed APK)

[image]

Generate the release Certificate:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/MyPath/my.new.keystore -alias mynewalias -storepass keystorepassword -keypass aliaspassword
```

EDIT: List the certificate fingerprints (SHA1, MD5) using this command line:

```
keytool -v -list -keystore yourkeystore -alias youralias
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a keystore that I use to sign all of my apps, how can see the SH1 Certificate when I sign my app with release certificate? I am asking that, because I will have to change the SH1 certificate in my  API console project.

Comment: keytool -v -list -keystore yourkeystore -alias youralias